# record extension file missing in Xlib

Tags: python, xlib

I tried running a linux keylogger called pykeylogger but ran into the following error:

"...from Xlib.ext import record
ImportError: cannot import name record"

I went into the ext directory of Xlib and saw there is no record.py in there. Is there somewhere I can get this file? Also, is there a reason it wouldn't have been installed with the rest of Xlib? I downloaded Xlib from here:

http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: The project is moving to GitHub: https://github.com/python-xlib/python-xlib (in progress). Py3 compatibility fixes are on the way.